# Service Fabric Multiple Communication Listeners

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Basic Idea - I have a stateless service that implements an Owin communication Listener over http to service WebApi based public clients.  I want to add a second listener that will receive requests within the cluster over Rpc using the built in ServiceRemotingListener().  The reason is that I don't want this listener to be public as it implements a non-public management interface for the stateless service.  Here is the setup...:

```
        protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new ServiceInstanceListener(initParams => new OwinCommunicationListener("MyWebService", new Startup(_options, this), initParams),"MyServiceHttp"),
            new ServiceInstanceListener(initParams => new ServiceRemotingListener<Interfaces.IConfig>(initParams, this),"MyServiceRpc")           
        };
    }
```

When I add the second listener, I get an exception starting the app...

```
                 this.serverHandle = WebApp.Start(this.listeningAddress, appBuilder => this.startup.Configuration(appBuilder));
```

> Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' in System.ServiceModel.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' in System.ServiceModel.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' in System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll
>   --multiple repeats---
>   Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' in System.Fabric.dll

(not sure how to get the exception details.  My "try {} " surrounding
 did not trap an exception.)

Once in this state, I get subsequent exceptions as the service attempts to auto-restart - the errors are about port sharing.

Anything I can do to make WebApi communication listeners work alongside ServiceRemotingListener?  I am assuming at this point that under the hood, ServiceRemotingListener is using http as well and they don't play nicely together.

Comment: It looks like I was using a port blocked by the firewall.  I get the same exception but now I also get a CommunicationException with the same error but it identifies the port as 0.0.0.0:8080.  " A TCP error (10013: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions) occurred while listening on IP Endpoint=0.0.0.0:8080."

Comment: ServiceRemotingListener doesn't use HTTP. Can you get ServiceRemotingLIstener to work on its own, without the OwinCommunicationListener?

Comment: I'll give it a go and report back tomorrow.  Thanks!

Comment: When I set up the ServiceRemotingListener on its own, the node reports {"Endpoints":{"MyRpc":"net.tcp:\/\/localhost:8083\/2c44446c-4c4e-479a-ac48-13c5b664b8c6\/0b91d2a3-80c3-4c30-b9b4-490672a8c077-130979017853872413"}}.  Looking into why this decided to use tcp....

Comment: ..and when I add the IOwinCommunicationListener back using a listening address "http://+:8083/bc35bdfc-c488-473e-aaa2-5bdc6b763b9f/130979290464827805/99d163c8-e462-4a8f-8bfa-821d9308790e", I get the "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions" error again.

Comment: I tried swapping the order and the http listener throws and exception.  Sounds like tcp and http communication listeners are not working together (either OWIN or net.tcp or both don't like to share).  One option I am investigating is whether I can set different ports.... we'll see.

Answer (score 8):

ok, the solution turned out to be straight forward but not obvious.  The docs seem to encourage port sharing approach even though the TCP/RPC and HTTP don't play together.

**Basically, I added a second endpoint to the service manifest** even though the docs say that each service can only listen on one port.

I left the default / first endpoint for the ServiceRemotingListener to register and added a second that listened specifically to port 8083.

```
<Endpoint Name="ServiceEndpoint" Protocol="http" Type ="Input"/>
<Endpoint Name="ServiceEndpoint2" Protocol="http" Port="8083" Type ="Input"/>
```

Then **in the IOwinCommunicationsListener, I specified the second endpoint** which picked up the alternative port number (I assumed the ServiceInstanceListener would use the default/first end point).

```
var codePackageActivationContext = this.serviceInitializationParameters.CodePackageActivationContext;
var port = codePackageActivationContext.GetEndpoint("ServiceEndpoint2").Port;
```

The CreateServiceInstanceListeners were left without any extra config.  As above, I wonder if I could use the ServiceRemoteListenerSettings to force the ServiceRemotinglistener to use the alternative port instead of the IOwinCommunicationsListener above)

```
        return new[]
        {
            new ServiceInstanceListener(initParams => new ServiceRemotingListener<Interfaces.IConfig>(initParams, this),"MyRpc"),
            new ServiceInstanceListener(initParams => new OwinCommunicationListener("ShopifyWebService", new Startup(_options, this), initParams),"MyOwin")
               };
```

Hope this helps save someone else a lot of time.

Comment: If I have multiple input endpoints, how would I call these endpoints from the browser?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your Q but here is an attempt.  Easiest one first - the second listener I already set to port 8083 so I can access through http://hostname:8083/<yourpath>.  For the first listener, within the service you can query the port that ServiceFabric assigned through the service instance listener and then publish or write that value.  Alternatively, from a service fabric client, you could use the name service via service partition client to query the service endpoint.  See the Wordcount demo and look at the stateless service for how it looks up the stateful service endpoint.

Comment: Also, it looks like it is important which endpoint is specified first and which listener is created first.

Comment: can you override which endpoint you use based on a setting within appmanifest? for example if you want to switch entire application from http to https just by changing 1 config setting?