# can i use two different kind of listener in service fabric service?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a stateless service which i am using as a websocket server.For that I am using ICommunicationListener. Also I want to call the methods of this service using ServiceProxy. So for that I am using ServiceRemotingListener.

```
internal sealed class Stateless : StatelessService, ICommunicationListener, IStatelessServiceInterface
{        
    public Stateless(StatelessServiceContext context)
        : base(context){ }      

    protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
    {           
        return new List<ServiceInstanceListener>()
        {
            new ServiceInstanceListener((context) =>this.CreateServiceRemotingListener(context)),
            new ServiceInstanceListener(_ => this)
        };
    }.....
```

So when I am using both the listener, after running the application in Diagnostic Event I am getting message : socket is going to close.So websocket is not working.

So I want to know that can I use two types of listener together ? or is there any solution for my problem?

Comment: Can you show OpenAsync? Is the reasons why socket is closed known? Is firewall configured? What do you have in Endpoints section of ServiceManifest?

Comment: If i don't use the remotingListener, the websocket is working fine.

Comment: <Endpoint Protocol="http" Name="ServiceEndpoint" Type="Input" Port="8081"/>

Comment: Please add updates to the question itself. And OpenAsync is still interesting.

Answer (score -1):

this is my OpenAsync:

```
public Task<string> OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
        EndpointResourceDescription serviceEndpoint = this.serviceContext.CodePackageActivationContext.GetEndpoint("ServiceEndpoint");
        int port = serviceEndpoint.Port;
        this.listeningAddress = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "http://+:{0}/{1}{2}", port, this.appRoot, this.webSocketRoot);
        this.publishAddress = this.listeningAddress.Replace("+", FabricRuntime.GetNodeContext().IPAddressOrFQDN);

        this.Start();
        return Task.FromResult(this.publishAddress);
    }
```

Comment: So, basically, you are publishing the same address and port for both listeners? It would not work like that. At least add the second endpoint with different name and path both names to the first instance listener and to the second. Or just change port in code of OpenAsync.

Comment: yes.I have a second endpoint with different name.                          <Endpoint Protocol="http" Name="ServiceEndpoint2" Type="Input" />.             But i am not understanding this you told : "path both names to the first instance listener and to the second"

Comment: Just a mistype. I meant that you need to put the names to instance listeners so each listener would know which endpoint belongs to it. By the way, endpoint for Remoting has Internal type, not Input and uses TCP.

Comment: I am not getting any idea of how to put the endpoints names to instance listeners.

Comment: [Link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34958875/2152061). You don't specify endpoint name when you create instance listener if there is only one endpoint and have to specify if there are more than one.